# OSM - Offline query for my IONIC/CORDOVA project

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, openstreetmap

I'm pretty new to OSM (OpenStreetMap). I'm developing a cross platform mobile application with IONIC/CORDOVA.

I want to save OSM data in my database. Is to possible to save osm data in SQLite? Or anything better than SQLite for this project such as JSON? If it is possible then how can I manipulate/query data from there?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Ashikur, you've got 3 questions in this one question - please create them as separate questions. Also, asking for a working example is not really the way stackoverflow works, you are more likely to get useful answers if you post what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @Simon, Thank you. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can export OSM data to lots of formats, and you can save that data in a database. However, you cannot use [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) in SQLite so you have to come up with your own query system.

If you already have a (semi) working system using PostGIS I'd suggest implementing a (web) API to serve the data to your app from a database running on a server instead of trying to bundle all needed data and do the querying on a mobile phone.

Alternatively if the app uses data that can be precomputed you could run the queries using PostGIS and bundle the result with your app. (In GeoJSON, CSV, KML, ... format)

This is of course dependent on the type of data and queries that you need - if you extend your question to include that I might be able to give a more specific answer.

Comment: I have already converted OSM data of a city into GeoJSON format. Now I want to fetch co-ordinates (Polyline points) of driving directions (from origin to destination) from that GeoJSON file. So that I can determine whether any particular co-ordinate is on that specific route. How can I do it? Thank You. @Simon Groenewolt